# capture image from camera and store in database

Tags: android

I Want to store image into SQLite database Which Captured from camera ..this my code for capture image from camera after i struct to store that images into data-base.....

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.photobtn:
        i = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(i, camaradata);
        break;
    case R.id.submit:
        break;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        bmp = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        imageview.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    }
}
```

Comment: storing images into database is not a good idea, just store it to external storage and maybe save a link into your database...

Comment: @mindsonic ok..i agree with you..but can you help me for that how to store image in external storage.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use "blob" to store images(bitmap).

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE Funny(picid TEXT,myimage BLOB,gender TEXT,country TEXT)");
```

insert data using this:

```
public void insert(String string,byte[] bytes,String gender,String country) {
 ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
 cv.put("picid",string);
 cv.put("myimage",bytes);
 cv.put("gender", gender);
 cv.put("country", country);
 getWritableDatabase().insert("Funny","gender", cv);
 Log.e("inserted", "inserted");
 }
```

eg: to store an image in to db

```
public void insertImg(int id , Bitmap img ) {   


    byte[] data = getBitmapAsByteArray(img); // this is a function

    db.insert("01",data,"male","Pakistan");

}

 public static byte[] getBitmapAsByteArray(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0, outputStream);       
    return outputStream.toByteArray();
}
```

and to retrieve an image from db

```
public Bitmap getImage(int i){

    String qu = "select myimage from Funny where picid=" + i ;
    Cursor cur = db.rawQuery(qu, null);

    if (cur.moveToFirst()){
        byte[] imgByte = cur.getBlob(0);
        cur.close();
        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imgByte, 0, imgByte.length);
    }
    if (cur != null && !cur.isClosed()) {
        cur.close();
    }       

    return null ;
}
```

Comment: can i insert this data by using of "contentvalue" object..??and how..??

Answer (score 0):

storing images into database is not a good idea, just store it to external storage and maybe save a link into your database.

Good tutorial on data-storage:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html

then save the path to your database if necessary:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

or simply into the shared preferences:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html